# How do I restore Dashboard widget list? (Launchpad-style adding)

Tags: launchpad, dashboard, macos

When using a tutorial to clear Launchpad of its mess I had in /Applications, I accidentally cleared Dashboard's list of widgets when I click the (+) button to add downloaded widgets at the same time, kind of like Launchpad's viewing of apps.

Here is my Dashboard:

[image: Dashboard, normal state]

And here it is when I click the (+) button to add downloaded widgets in the bottom left corner of Dashboard:

[image: No widgets to be found]

I believe it will only show new widgets I download. How can I get it to show all of my widgets again—including the default, built-in widgets?

(This is my Launchpad: it looks similar to the "add widgets" of Dashboard.app in Mountain Lion, but I am looking how to restore my list of widgets in Dashboard, not Launchpad.)

[image: Launchpad, 10.8.2]

Also, it probably doesn't make a large difference, but my Dashboard is set as a Space and not an overlay right now.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same problem, but now have a partial solution:

If you want to refresh the list entirely, delete the .db file located in `"~/Library/Application Support/Dock/"`, followed by running `killall Dock`. This forces the Dock to refresh its list of widgets. Unfortunately, the list of apps in Launchpad will also be reset.

You can remove these individually via

```
sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/*.db "DELETE from apps WHERE title='APP_NAME';" && killall Dock
```

(from http://www.wikihow.com/Delete-Apps-from-Launchpad-in-Mac-Os-X-Lion, which adds:

```
 Replace APP_NAME with the name of the unwanted app as it’s displayed in LaunchPad.
```

)

I wish I knew how to add widgets manually, but I really don't know much unix... If it's any help to those trying to find a better solution, the widgets are located in `/Library/Widgets`.

**Update**

In the end I just decided to use [Launchpad Manager](http://launchpadmanager.com/) to delete apps. It also functions as a widget manager.